# How to pipeline stderr in cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, redirection, pipe

Some programs would prefer to output the help message in stderr. I want to search the help message with `grep` command, `xx /? | grep regex`?

How could i do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can redirect stderr to stdout by using `2>&1`, and then pipe stdout into `grep`.

So, what I think you want is this:

```
xx /? 2>&1 | grep regex
```

Comment: what does &1 means?

Comment: To specify redirection to existing handles, use the ampersand `&` character followed by the handle number that you want to redirect (that is, `&handle#`). stdin is handle #0, stdout is handle #1, and stderr is handle #2.

Comment: @martineau are there other handles or can handles be created by windows api ?

Comment: @beppe9000: Standard input (`stdin`), standard output (`stdout`) and standard error (`stderr`) are the ony ones standardized. The values `0`, `1`, & `2`, correspond to the C language Unix OS "file descriptors", so in theory there could be other numbers — however I don't know if the Windows `cmd` console or the MS C runtime library supports them or not.