# Pipe second output (errors) in batch

Tags: command-line, batch, pipe, stderr

I have a batch file in which I need to pipe an exe's output to a command. However, the output is reading as error messages so it is not piping it. For example:

`mycommand.exe > out.txt` would have nothing in out.txt 
 but 
`mycommand.exe 2>out.txt` has the correct output in the out.txt file.

My question is what the pipe `|` equivilent is for the `2>` in batch? I attempted `2|` but it failed to give a different output.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/452763/how-to-pipleline-stderr-in-cmd-exe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pipleline stderr in cmd.exe?](https://superuser.com/questions/452763/how-to-pipleline-stderr-in-cmd-exe)

Comment: Yes it does, I swear I searched **that title** and nothing relevent came up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Pleased to have been able to help